# ul li dropdown, bottom objects go down when i open menu

Tags: jquery, css

When I open the ul dropdown menu, I don't want the underlying objects to slide, how can I do that?

```js
$("ul").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});
```

```css
ul {
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
  width:250px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  
}
ul li:not(.init) {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display:none
  }
textarea{
  resize:none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="selected-change">
<li class="init">Select</li>
<li>Example 1</li>
<li>Example 2</li>
<li>Example 3</li>
<li>Example 4</li>
<li>Example 5</li>
<li>Example 6</li>
</ul>
<textarea placeholder="...."></textarea>
```

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you put absolute positon to the menu it should work

Comment: yes I know, but this time it brings the underlying objects to the top, so I felt the need to ask a question.